# Can Newtonsoft.JSON create extra level of hierarchy when serializing an object?

Tags: .net, json.net

Suppose I have the following class:

```
    private class ErrorPayloadItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

If `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` it, I get something like this:

```
{"code": ...,"message": ...}
```

I would like it to be nested like this:

```
{"error": {"code": ..., "message": ...}}
```

Do I have to create an extra class in C# for that:

```
    private class ErrorPayload
    {
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public ErrorPayloadItem Error { get; set; }
    }
```

Or can I somehow instruct Newtonsoft.JSON to introduce the extra level through some configuration?

Comment: There's no way to do it automatically via configuration, but you could use an anonymous type, e.g.: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { error = errorPayloadItem } ); `.  Otherwise you'd have to make a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) which quite honestly is more work that creating the wrapper class (which could be generic).

Comment: If that is the case - arrange your comment as the answer, so I could credit you.